# Eclipse cant create new java projects

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, opensuse

I am running Eclipse 4.5.2 (Mars) on openSUSE Tumbleweed. Unfortunately I cannot create Java projects because after clicking on new->Java Projects, nothing happens...

I already reinstalled eclipse, cleared the metadata, removed the user data from my home directory. Nothing worked.

I just get the following error message in my log:
name= unhandled event loop exception; plugin= org.eclipse.ui;

Exception Stack Trace:

```
ava.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabFolder.gtk_switch_page(TabFolder.java:570)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowProc(Widget.java:2009)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4723)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._gtk_widget_show(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.gtk_widget_show(OS.java:14774)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabFolder.createItem(TabFolder.java:311)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabItem.createWidget(TabItem.java:123)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabItem.<init>(TabItem.java:75)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.BuildPathsBlock.createControl(BuildPathsBlock.java:228)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.JavaCapabilityConfigurationPage.createControl(JavaCapabilityConfigurationPage.java:162)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.createPageControls(Wizard.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createPageControls(WizardDialog.java:705)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createContents(WizardDialog.java:597)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:430)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1096)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.NewWizardShortcutAction.run(NewWizardShortcutAction.java:123)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4481)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1329)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3819)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3430)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
```

Stack Trace

```
eclipse.buildId=4.5.2.M20160212-1500
java.version=1.8.0_77
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=de_DE
Command-line arguments:  -data file:/home/andi/workspace/eclipse/ -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You haven't specified the Desktop environment you are running Eclipse on (KDE, GNOME, LXDE), anyway Eclipse seems [not to be very compatible with the new GTK3](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=430736).

I solved the issue forcing eclipse to work with the GTK2, you can do that adding the following two lines in your `eclipse.ini` file :

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

Make sure you add the two lines above the `--launcher.appendVmargs` line.

Comment: Thank you so much! That works!

For other guys with the same problem, you can find the eclipse.ini in "/usr/lib64/eclipse/" or "/usr/lib/eclipse/". There you have to add the two lines above the "--launcher.appendVmargs" line.

Comment: Works for me as as well! Eclipse Mars 2 for Java EE

Comment: FYI: make sure you add the lines __before__ the `-vmargs` line! All the best to those who are struggling with eclipse right now.

Comment: In my case it was `/opt/eclipse-sdk-bin-4.5/eclipse.ini` . Is there `eclipse.ini` or something similar somewhere in users home directory?

Comment: I had the same problem on 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04. The fix worked for me, indicating that the problem and its fix are not specific to openSUSE. Thanks.